# Create Lookup from List

Tags: c#

I want to create a `Lookup` from the list

```
List<User> users = new List<User>() { new User() { id = "1", code = "a" },
                                      new User() {id="2", code= "a" },
                                      new User() {id="3", code= "a" },
                                      new User() {id="4", code= "b" },
                                      new User() {id="1", code= "b" }
            };
```

The code I wrote is

```
Lookup<string, string> lkup = (Lookup<string, string>)users.ToLookup(k => k.id, k => k.code);
```

Though, this works, I endup with a Lookup in which I can't find the values.

Second, I don't understand why I can't create a `Lookup` using something like

```
Lookup<string, string> lkup = users.ToLookup<string,string>(
```

Comment: What do you mean "cant find the values"? Can you give an example of looking for the values and the expected result?

Comment: 1. What do you mean by "can't find the values"? `lkup["1"]` should return that first user's `code` just fine. You really should get rid of the cast, though, and just use `ILookup<TKey, TValue>`; there's no point in casting to the concrete class. 2. Um, because that's not a complete statement? You kinda have to pass the arguments to `ToLookup` and add a close paren and a semicolon.

Comment: @MikeHixson: I wrote 'var output = lkup.Where(l => l.Key == "1").ToList();' and could not get the values

Comment: You can just do `var t = lkup["1"]` to get an `IEnumerable<string>`

Comment: My question is not what alternative I have. My question is why LINQ is not providing the values?

Answer (score 0):

The values in your original code are there.  You can't see them until you enumerate them.  the following will print each key followed by its values on the next line:

```
List<User> users = new List<User>() { new User() { id = "1", code = "a" },
                          new User() {id="2", code= "a" },
                          new User() {id="3", code= "a" },
                          new User() {id="4", code= "b" },
                          new User() {id="1", code= "b" }
};
Lookup<string, string> lkup = (Lookup<string,string>)users.ToLookup(x => x.id, x => x.code);
foreach(var k in lkup)
{
    Console.WriteLine(k.Key);
    foreach(var v in k)
    {
        Console.Write($"{v} ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

This:

```
Lookup<string, string> lkup = users.ToLookup<string,string>(k => k.id, k => k.code);
```

Won't work because `lkup` must be `ILookup` not `Lookup`

```
ILookup<string, string> lkup = users.ToLookup(k => k.id, k => k.code);
```

Will produce the same thing as casting to `Lookup`.

Here's the class I used for the list:

```
class User
{
    public string id = "";
    public string code = "";
}
```

Comment: The last piece of code gives a compilation error "string does not contain a definition of id"

Comment: Sorry, had the `<string,string>` part in there, but didn't need it.